# How to find the Openshift Cluster API address using rest api

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, okd

how to find the the cluster api address using rest api. Like cluster ID can be collected from */apis/config.openshift.io/v1/clusterversions*.

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API address is available in the `apiServerURL` field in [the status of the Infrastructure object](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/rest_api/config_apis/infrastructure-config-openshift-io-v1.html#status), available at [/apis/config.openshift.io/v1/infrastructures](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/rest_api/config_apis/infrastructure-config-openshift-io-v1.html#apisconfig-openshift-iov1infrastructures).